# Using dplyr group_by summarise how to keep a variable occuring at the maximum of another variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, using the airquality data,
I want to calculate the maximum temperature for each month. 
Then keep the day on which this maximum temperature occurred.

```
library(dplyr)
# Maximum temperature per month
airqualitymax <- airquality %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>% 
    summarise(maxtemp = max(Temp))
# Day of the month on which the max occured
airquality %>% 
    left_join(airqualitymax, by = "Month") %>%
    filter(Temp == maxtemp)
```

Now it appears that the day is not unique, 
but suppose it was unique, Is there a way to select the day on which the maximum occurs in the summarise() directly?

Comment: Do you mean `... summarise(maxtemp = max(Temp), day = Day[which.max(Temp)])`?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I didn't know about `which.max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `slice` to keep the row that have the maximum 'Temp' for each 'Month'

```
airquality %>% 
   group_by(Month) %>% 
   slice(which.max(Temp))
```

---

A faster option would be to `arrange` the 'Temp' in descending (or ascending) and get the first observation (or last `slice(n())`)

```
airquality %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  arrange(desc(Temp)) %>%
  slice(1L)
```

Comment: Great, I accept your answer. I also like the `sumarise(day = Day[which.max(Temp)])` solution provided by @docendo discimus above, because summarise gives a nice short data frame.

Comment: @PaulRougieux  I thought you wanted the entire row.

Comment: both ways are fine. I wasn't clear about this in my question. In the real data, I'm looking at the year in which the maximum consumption occurred for each country. At the moment, I'm exploring the dataset and the more information the better, so I'll use your solution, with the entire row. Then when I implement a function to do this I might use the other data frame, with a shorter row containing only country, max(consumption) and year.

Comment: @PaulRougieux  You can use the `%>% select(columnsofinterest)` to the above solution to subset the columns